# Play json looking not working well in this case

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have following code to work with play json

import play.api.libs.json.Json

```
trait A {
  def x: Option[Int]

  def y: Option[String]
}

case class A1(x: Option[Int] = Some(1), y: Option[String]) extends A

object PlayJsonBug {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val A1Reader = Json.reads[A1]
    implicit val A1Writer = Json.writes[A1]
    val str = """{"y":"xyz"}"""
    val a: A1 = Json.fromJson[A1](Json.parse(str)).get
    println(a)
  }


}
```

case class A1 has default value for `x` which is `Some (1)`.
when i parse `{"y":"xyz"}` ,the result is `A1(None,Some(xyz))`,I thought that the default value should be used here,that tis,the result should be `A1(Some(1),Some(xyz))`

Is this a bug?Or how I could work around this problem

Comment: I'd like to know which version of play-json you are using. I remember browsing through the git history of play-json and seeing recent (aka less than a year old) commits related to handling of case classes with default arguments. I don't remember the details however...

Comment: Thanks @FredericA.I am using Play 2.6.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Json.reads` is a scala macro whose implementation doesn't care for default values since it only iterates through all of the class' case accessors. You will need to implement your own `play.api.libs.json.Reads` to support falling back to default parameters in case of not finding the value in json.

It could look something like this (for Play 2.5.x):

```scala
implicit object A1Reads extends Reads[A1] {

    private val generatedReads = Json.reads[A1]

    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[A1] = {
        // re-use reads, but replace None for x with default param
        generatedReads.reads(json).map {
            case A1(None, y) => A1(Some(1), y)
            case valid => valid
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dexmo for the helpful answer!